# Two unit vectors  and  in $\Bbb R^n$ satisfy $x\cdot y= \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Two unit vectors $x$ and $y$ in $\Bbb R ^n$ satisfy $x\cdot y= \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$
Evaluate

A) angle between $x$ and $y$ in Radian.

$\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$ is in unit circle and that is $30$ degrees so in measuring angles in radians that would be  $ \frac{π}{6} $

B) $y\cdot (3x−5y)$

Apply dot product rule, x · (y + z) = x · y + x · z

$$
3x·y-5y·y    
$$
Then apply, x · x = $|x|^2=1$
$$
3x·y - 5|y|^2
$$
and since x · y = $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$
$$
3\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} - 5(1)
$$
Final answer:
$$
3\frac{\sqrt 3}{2} - 5
$$

What about now?

C)the length of $7 x+2 y$

$$
||v|| = v · v
$$
$$
||v|| = (7x+2y)·(7x+2y)
$$
$$
= 49|x|^2+4|y|^2+28x·y
$$
$$
= 49+4+28\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
$$
$$
||v||= 53+14\sqrt{3}
$$

**EDITED**

Comment: It is IMPOSSIBLE for the dot product of two UNIT vectors to be "$3\sqrt{2}$! The dot product of two unit vectors is **less than** 1. $cos(30)= \sqrt{3}/2$.

Comment: I saw my mistake, I updated it. You know there's a nicer way of pointing it out.

Comment: You should update the title as well. By the way, write `$\Bbb R$` to get $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Yes, I have done it. Thank you!

Comment: B is not quite correct. Try to think of $x$ and $y$ as vectors, not algebraic variables. So you should apply the definition of the dot product, instead of carrying out algebra.

Comment: @tangentbundle "instead of carrying out algebra"? Using the properties of the dot product to evaluate the expression is still algebra.

Comment: C is wrong. Use $\| v \| = \sqrt{v\cdot v}$.

Comment: @jjagmath Sure. By algebra, I mean high school level symbolic manipulation. Students make this mistake very often. I encourage the OP to think what $y^2$ is supposed to mean for a vector $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second part, use distribution to open up the brackets to give $3\mathbb{y}\cdot \mathbb{x} -5\mathbb{y}\cdot \mathbb{y}$

(you cannot write $y^2$ for vector quantities)

Now use commutativity of the dot product to write it as: $3\mathbb{x}\cdot \mathbb{y} -5\mathbb{y}\cdot \mathbb{y}$

Then recognise that a dot product of a vector with itself equals a scalar which is simple the square of the vector's magnitude. So $\mathbb{y}\cdot \mathbb{y} = |\mathbb{y}|^2 = 1$

I think you can finish up now.

For part c), your method (using straight up Pythagoras' theorem) is only applicable for two orthogonal vectors (at right angles to each other). This is not the case here. Solve it using $\mathbb v \cdot \mathbb v = |\mathbb v|^2$ like someone else suggested in the comments to the main question. So expand $(7\mathbb x + 2\mathbb y) \cdot (7\mathbb x + 2\mathbb y)$ and take the square root of the resulting scalar. Alternatively use a geometric approach (parallelogram rule for vector addition) and the cosine rule (this is more tedious, but gets you the same answer).

Comment: I'm trying to follow, so what happens to 3⋅? If −5⋅ = -5(1) = -5.

Comment: The dot product seems simple, but what confuses me is the  being multiplied to (3−5).

Comment: @Sampaguita The y is being distributed out - it is the dot product analogue of normal algebraic distribution. a(b+c) = ab + ac. With regard to what to do with the 3x.y term, you've already been given the value of x.y, scalar multiplication is just, well, scaling.

Comment: I've updated the answer, is that right now?

Comment: @Sampaguita Your answer for part b) is correct. For part c) it is wrong. Your method is only applicable for two orthogonal vectors (at right angles to each other). This is not the case here. Solve it using $\mathbb v \cdot \mathbb v = |\mathbb v|^2$ like someone else suggested in the comments to the main question. So expand $(7\mathbb x + 2\mathbb y) \cdot (7\mathbb x + 2\mathbb y)$ and take the square root of the resulting scalar. Alternatively use a geometric approach and the cosine rule (this is more tedious, but gets you the same answer).

Comment: You are right, I did not see that. I don't know why I assumed it right away to be a unit vector.

Comment: @Sampaguita x and y are indeed unit vectors. Unit vector simply means having length one. It has no relation to orthogonality (being at right angles to each other).